# Контроль персонажа по 3-м точкам Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется такой метод контроля персонажем который крутится в апдейте в бесконечном раннере:

```cs
private void PlayerMovement()
    {
        moveVector = Vector3.zero;
        moveVector.z = variableJoystick.Horizontal * moveHorizontalSpeed; // был moveVectorZ 
        moveVector.y = gravityForce;
        moveVector.x -= moveVectorX;
   
        characterController.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);
        characterController.center = new Vector3(0, 0.85f, -0.3f);
    }
```

По Х координате задается дефолтное ускорение вперед, по Y кастомная гравитация и Z - горизонтальное управление с помощью джойстика. Проблема в том, что нужно переписать данный метод так, чтобы оставить управление джойстиком, но чтобы при свайпах игрок оказывался в нужной координате.
**Проблема**: При использовании метода описаного ниже персонаж не останавливается на нужной координате, а продолжает движение и как переписать данный код, чтобы было дефолтное управление в бесконечном раннере - свайпами.

```cs
private void CoordinatesMovement()
    {
        float leftPos = -2.3f;
        float rightPos = 5.3f;
        float centerPos = 2.0f;
        
        if (variableJoystick.Horizontal < 0)
        {
            moveVectorZ = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, leftPos, Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if (variableJoystick.Horizontal > 0)
        {
            moveVectorZ = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, rightPos, Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if(variableJoystick.Horizontal == 0)
        {
            moveVectorZ = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            moveVectorZ = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, centerPos, Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
```

P.S.>> Использование линейной интерполяции - это тестовый вариант.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
 private void PlayerMovement()
    {
        moveVector = Vector3.zero;

        moveVector.y = gravityForce;
        moveVector.x -= moveVectorX;

        float input = variableJoystick.Horizontal;

        if (Mathf.Abs(input) > .1f)
        {
            if (!didChangeLastFrame)
            {
                didChangeLastFrame = true;
                laneNumber += (int) Mathf.Sign(input);
                laneNumber = Mathf.Clamp(laneNumber, 0, lanesCount);
            }

            if (laneNumber == 0)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger(IsIdleB);
                animator.SetTrigger(IsFly);
            }

            if (laneNumber == 2)
            {
                animator.SetTrigger(IsIdleC);
                animator.SetTrigger(IsFly);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            didChangeLastFrame = false;
        }

        characterController.Move(moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        newPos.z = Mathf.Lerp(newPos.z, firstLanePos + (laneNumber * laneDistance), Time.deltaTime * sideSpeed);

        transform.position = newPos;
        characterController.center = new Vector3(0, 0.85f, -0.3f);
    }
```